# Deleting multiple selected values from datagrid. Only first value is being deleted

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a datagrid with a checkbox column where the user selects which records to delete. Since there are multiple values I build a list of string to be separated by comma and then deleted one a time through the loop. However, only the first selected value is being deleted, the code is ignoring the remaining values.

I but my variable on a messagebox and the first value appears by itself, but anything after that is shows up on one line and not separated.

I have looked at this code several times, but I cannot see where I am going wrong.

Here is my loop for checking selected rows.

```
Private Sub btnDeleteRecord_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDeleteRecord.Click

    Dim idCollection As New StringCollection()
    Dim strID As String = String.Empty

    Try

        'Store each selected record on string collection
        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In grdDeleteRecord.Rows
            If row.Cells(0).Value() Then

                strID = row.Cells(1).Value()
                idCollection.Add(strID)

                'Call procedure to delete multiple records
                DeleteMultipleRecords(idCollection)

            End If

        Next

    Catch ex As Exception

        MsgBox(ex.ToString())


    End Try

End Sub

Here is the procedure where the records get deleted

Private Sub DeleteMultipleRecords(ByVal idCollection As StringCollection)

        Dim IDs As String = ""

        'Create string builder to store 
        'delete commands separated by ;

        For Each id As String In idCollection
            IDs += id.ToString() & ","

        Next

        Try

                Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor

                **DataSheetTableAdapter.DeleteRecord(strIDs)** 'This is only deleting the first value


                Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default



        Catch ex As Exception
            Dim errorMsg As String = "Error in Deletion"
            errorMsg += ex.Message
            Throw New Exception(errorMsg)

        Finally


        End Try

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your problem is that you are calling the `DeleteMultipleRecord` sub multiple times when you only want to call it once. I think you maybe want to iterate your data grid, collecting all the checked rows, and after they are all collected, perform the delete operation one time only.

I simply moved the delete operation outside of the row iteration loop because it is designed to delete many things at once.

```
Private Sub btnDeleteRecord_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDeleteRecord.Click
    Dim idCollection As New StringCollection()
    Dim strID As String = String.Empty
    Try
        'Store each selected record on string collection
        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In grdDeleteRecord.Rows
            If row.Cells(0).Value() Then
                strID = row.Cells(1).Value()
                idCollection.Add(strID)
                'Call procedure to delete multiple records
                'DeleteMultipleRecords(idCollection)
            End If
        Next    
        ' moved to here.
        DeleteMultipleRecords(idCollection)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString())
    End Try
End Sub
```